# Vim: show subfold headers inside closed folds

Tags: vim, code-folding

Is it possible to show the headers of all subfolds under their respective parent folds in vim? This would be incredibly useful, for example when writing latex, where the document may have 4-5 levels of folds, and you want to get a quick overview of the outline. For example, it would be nice to see output like this:

```
  2 +--342 lines: \chapter{Methodology}--------------------------------------
  6 +---210 lines: \section{some section}------------------------------------
 46 +---- 12 lines: \subsection{some subsection}-----------------------------
 58 +----158 lines: \subsection{some subsection}-----------------------------
216 +---197 lines: \section{some other section}------------------------------
279 +---- 42 lines: \subsection{some other subsection}-----------------------
```

and, ideally, to be able to open and close those sections without opening the parent section.

Comment: You can define your own function to show the fold text that you prefer and set the `foldtext` option to it. See `:help fold-foldtext` for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @ElIsra, but I'm not very familiar with the vim language yet. I'll see what I can do, if I find time, but if someone else posts such a function, I'd probably accept that answer.

Comment: The problem with your idea is that subfolds, being contained within other folds, are not supposed to be visible at all. That's the point of a fold: closing a fold hides everything within this fold's boundaries. Are you looking for an [outlining system](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657)?

Comment: @romainl: thanks for the link. That looks like overkill to me, and not quite what I wanted, but I will try it. I know folds weren't intended this way, but that's not really a good reason not to try it.

Comment: Also, VOoM doesn't appear to like partial latex files (I submitted a [bug](https://github.com/vim-voom/vim-voom.github.com/issues/4))